# Finding analytical solutions for given equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, maple, mathematica

I have a system of 6 equations with 6 variables. The 6 variables are $t11, t12, t13, t21, t22, t23$ and the rest of the symbols in the equations are known symbols. I want to find all the possible analytical solutions of the 6 variables $t11, t12, t13, t21, t22, t23$ as expressions of the known symbols.
Here are the 6 equations (I wrote them in Matlab):

```
eq1 = pz1^2 + 2*pz1*t11*vz1 + t11^2*vx1^2 + t11^2*vy1^2 + t11^2*vz1^2 == qz1^2 + 2*qz1*t21*uz1 + t21^2*ux1^2 + t21^2*uy1^2 + t21^2*uz1^2
eq2 = pz2^2 + 2*pz2*t12*vz2 + t12^2*vx2^2 + t12^2*vy2^2 + t12^2*vz2^2 == qz2^2 + 2*qz2*t22*uz2 + t22^2*ux2^2 + t22^2*uy2^2 + t22^2*uz2^2
eq3 = pz3^2 + 2*pz3*t13*vz3 + t13^2*vx3^2 + t13^2*vy3^2 + t13^2*vz3^2 == qz3^2 + 2*qz3*t23*uz3 + t23^2*ux3^2 + t23^2*uy3^2 + t23^2*uz3^2
eq4 = pz1*pz2 + pz2*t11*vz1 + pz1*t12*vz2 + t11*t12*vx1*vx2 + t11*t12*vy1*vy2 + t11*t12*vz1*vz2 == qz1*qz2 + qz2*t21*uz1 + qz1*t22*uz2 + t21*t22*ux1*ux2 + t21*t22*uy1*uy2 + t21*t22*uz1*uz2
eq5 = pz2*pz3 + pz3*t12*vz2 + pz2*t13*vz3 + t12*t13*vx2*vx3 + t12*t13*vy2*vy3 + t12*t13*vz2*vz3 == qz2*qz3 + qz3*t22*uz2 + qz2*t23*uz3 + t22*t23*ux2*ux3 + t22*t23*uy2*uy3 + t22*t23*uz2*uz3
eq6 = pz1*pz3 + pz3*t11*vz1 + pz1*t13*vz3 + t11*t13*vx1*vx3 + t11*t13*vy1*vy3 + t11*t13*vz1*vz3 == qz1*qz3 + qz3*t21*uz1 + qz1*t23*uz3 + t21*t23*ux1*ux3 + t21*t23*uy1*uy3 + t21*t23*uz1*uz3
```

Notice that each equation is of the form:
$eq_i=left\_expression==right\_expression$

The equations are for sure correct (I checked them with known values and known solutions for $t11, t12, t13, t21, t22, t23$ and I indeed got equality of the left and right expressions in each equation).

But I need to get all the possible solutions for the general case.

When I tried to solve the equations using Matlab 'solve' command, it didn't finish the run (I waited for more than an hour).

> Can anyone suggest other ways of solving the equations?

The equations look solvable since they are all second degree polynomial equations (of 6 variables).

> Any chance that anyone here can try to solve the equations using 'Mathematica' or 'Maple' programs (since I don't have them). Or at least tell me if they are solvable in these programs and if so, I will buy the programs (the university will..).

Here is the full code in matlab so you can see how I built the equations (if anyone here is able to translate the code to Mathematica/Maple and check if the the equations are solvable there)

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

%The folowing 6 symbols are the UNKNOWN variables
syms t11 t12 t13 %parameters of the 3 lines of the first set
syms t21 t22 t23 %parameters of the 3 lines of the second set   

%The folowing symbols are the KNOWN variables
syms px1 py1 pz1
syms px2 py2 pz2
syms px3 py3 pz3

syms vx1 vy1 vz1
syms vx2 vy2 vz2
syms vx3 vy3 vz3    

syms qx1 qy1 qz1
syms qx2 qy2 qz2
syms qx3 qy3 qz3

syms ux1 uy1 uz1
syms ux2 uy2 uz2
syms ux3 uy3 uz3

%Trying to make the equations simpler, I assume all 6 lines pass through
%a point on the Z axis (but I prefer the general case)
lines1_points = [0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 ; pz1 pz2 pz3]; 
%lines1_points = [px1 px2 px3 ; py1 py2 py3 ; pz1 pz2 pz3];
lines1_vecs = [vx1 vx2 vx3 ; vy1 vy2 vy3 ; vz1 vz2 vz3];
lines2_points = [0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 ; qz1 qz2 qz3];
%lines2_points = [qx1 qx2 qx3 ; qy1 qy2 qy3 ; qz1 qz2 qz3];
lines2_vecs = [ux1 ux2 ux3 ; uy1 uy2 uy3 ; uz1 uz2 uz3];

vars1 = diag([t11 t12 t13]);
vars2 = diag([t21 t22 t23]);

T1 = lines1_points+lines1_vecs*vars1;
T2 = lines2_points+lines2_vecs*vars2;

T1_transpose = T1.';
T2_transpose = T2.';

part1 = T1_transpose*T1;
part2 = T2_transpose*T2;

eqs_symmetric_matrix = part1==part2;
expanded_eqs_symmetric_matrix = expand(eqs_symmetric_matrix);
%6 equations of the top upper matrix (first 3 equations are the diagonal)
eq1 = expanded_eqs_symmetric_matrix(1,1)
eq2 = expanded_eqs_symmetric_matrix(2,2)
eq3 = expanded_eqs_symmetric_matrix(3,3)
eq4 = expanded_eqs_symmetric_matrix(1,2)
eq5 = expanded_eqs_symmetric_matrix(2,3)
eq6 = expanded_eqs_symmetric_matrix(1,3)

eqs = [eq1; eq2; eq3; eq4; eq5; eq6];
fprintf('Trying to solve the equations (matlab does not succeed to solve the equations)\n');
[t11_sol,t12_sol,t13_sol,t21_sol,t22_sol,t23_sol] = solve(eqs,[t11,t12,t13,t21,t22,t23]);
fprintf('Finished solving the equations\n');
```

I will appreciate any help!

Thanks

Update:
Using the assumption that all the lines pass through the same point [0 0 z] and using the fact that all the directional vectors of the lines are unit. The new 6 equations are now:

```
eq1 = t11^2 + z^2 + 2*t11*z*(- vx1^2 - vy1^2 + 1)^(1/2) == t21^2 + z^2 + 2*t21*z*(- ux1^2 - uy1^2 + 1)^(1/2)
eq2 = t12^2 + z^2 + 2*t12*z*(- vx2^2 - vy2^2 + 1)^(1/2) == t22^2 + z^2 + 2*t22*z*(- ux2^2 - uy2^2 + 1)^(1/2)
eq3 = t13^2 + z^2 + 2*t13*z*(- vx3^2 - vy3^2 + 1)^(1/2) == t23^2 + z^2 + 2*t23*z*(- ux3^2 - uy3^2 + 1)^(1/2)
eq4 = z^2 + t11*z*(- vx1^2 - vy1^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t12*z*(- vx2^2 - vy2^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t11*t12*vx1*vx2 + t11*t12*vy1*vy2 + t11*t12*(- vx1^2 - vy1^2 + 1)^(1/2)*(- vx2^2 - vy2^2 + 1)^(1/2) == z^2 + t21*z*(- ux1^2 - uy1^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t22*z*(- ux2^2 - uy2^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t21*t22*ux1*ux2 + t21*t22*uy1*uy2 + t21*t22*(- ux1^2 - uy1^2 + 1)^(1/2)*(- ux2^2 - uy2^2 + 1)^(1/2)
eq5 = z^2 + t12*z*(- vx2^2 - vy2^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t13*z*(- vx3^2 - vy3^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t12*t13*vx2*vx3 + t12*t13*vy2*vy3 + t12*t13*(- vx2^2 - vy2^2 + 1)^(1/2)*(- vx3^2 - vy3^2 + 1)^(1/2) == z^2 + t22*z*(- ux2^2 - uy2^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t23*z*(- ux3^2 - uy3^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t22*t23*ux2*ux3 + t22*t23*uy2*uy3 + t22*t23*(- ux2^2 - uy2^2 + 1)^(1/2)*(- ux3^2 - uy3^2 + 1)^(1/2)
eq6 = z^2 + t11*z*(- vx1^2 - vy1^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t13*z*(- vx3^2 - vy3^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t11*t13*vx1*vx3 + t11*t13*vy1*vy3 + t11*t13*(- vx1^2 - vy1^2 + 1)^(1/2)*(- vx3^2 - vy3^2 + 1)^(1/2) == z^2 + t21*z*(- ux1^2 - uy1^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t23*z*(- ux3^2 - uy3^2 + 1)^(1/2) + t21*t23*ux1*ux3 + t21*t23*uy1*uy3 + t21*t23*(- ux1^2 - uy1^2 + 1)^(1/2)*(- ux3^2 - uy3^2 + 1)^(1/2)
```

Comment: Try something smaller, say, three quadratics in three variables, and see how long that takes, and how awful the solutions look. That might give you some idea of how much you're asking for with your six equations.

Comment: I've tried other system equations of 6 variables and it didn't take much time (a few minutes). Matlab actually did finish the running eventually (of the equations I wrote above) and I got the message: "Warning: Cannot find explicit solution". I'm not sure if it's because the equations are too complicated for it to solve.

Comment: So this is the set of equations resulting from solving the problem you posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297050). It is in fact quite hard, also for a computer. Let's see if it can be posed in such a way that it can be worked out.

Comment: Yes it is :). I was really hoping that this time the equations can be solved since they are not trigonometric equations anymore. But I still end up with too complicated equations.

Comment: I updated the question with the full code in matlab so it is now clear how I built the equations.

Answer (score 2):

In Maple syntax these equations would be:

```
eq1 := t11^2*vx1^2+t11^2*vy1^2+t11^2*vz1^2+2*pz1*t11*vz1+pz1^2
  = t21^2*ux1^2+t21^2*uy1^2+t21^2*uz1^2+2*qz1*t21*uz1+qz1^2;
eq2 := t12^2*vx2^2+t12^2*vy2^2+t12^2*vz2^2+2*pz2*t12*vz2+pz2^2
  = t22^2*ux2^2+t22^2*uy2^2+t22^2*uz2^2+2*qz2*t22*uz2+qz2^2;
eq3 := t13^2*vx3^2+t13^2*vy3^2+t13^2*vz3^2+2*pz3*t13*vz3+pz3^2
  = t23^2*ux3^2+t23^2*uy3^2+t23^2*uz3^2+2*qz3*t23*uz3+qz3^2;
eq4 := t11*t12*vx1*vx2+t11*t12*vy1*vy2+t11*t12*vz1*vz2+pz1*t12*vz2+pz2*t11*vz1+pz1*pz2
  = t21*t22*ux1*ux2+t21*t22*uy1*uy2+t21*t22*uz1*uz2+qz1*t22*uz2+qz2*t21*uz1+qz1*qz2; 
eq5 := t12*t13*vx2*vx3+t12*t13*vy2*vy3+t12*t13*vz2*vz3+pz2*t13*vz3+pz3*t12*vz2+pz2*pz3
  = t22*t23*ux2*ux3+t22*t23*uy2*uy3+t22*t23*uz2*uz3+qz2*t23*uz3+qz3*t22*uz2+qz2*qz3; 
eq6 := t11*t13*vx1*vx3+t11*t13*vy1*vy3+t11*t13*vz1*vz3+pz1*t13*vz3+pz3*t11*vz1+pz1*pz3
  = t21*t23*ux1*ux3+t21*t23*uy1*uy3+t21*t23*uz1*uz3+qz1*t23*uz3+qz3*t21*uz1+qz1*qz3;
```

However, given that this system solves a very general geometric problem, I would not expect it to have a compact solution.  Indeed, my attempts at getting a Groebner basis in the most efficient way possible in Maple 2017 consumes all of my available system memory almost instantly, and then fails.

```
Groebner:-Basis((lhs-rhs)~({eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6}),
 tdeg(t23, t22, t21, t13, t12, t11, vy3, vy2, vy1, vx3, vx2, vx1, qz3,
 qz2, qz1, pz3, pz2, pz1, uy3, uy2, uy1, ux3, ux2, ux1, vz3, vz2, vz1,
 uz3, uz2, uz1));
```

This is pretty good evidence that the closed form solution to this system is probably too large to be useful.

You'll probably need to consider a different approach to this problem.

Comment: Thanks. good to know.
I actually tried to get the solutions in matlab in many ways. one of the ways was to reduce each time the number of variables by one by finding one variable as expressions of the current rest variables. when I got to the forth variable, I got a HUGE expression that matlab couldn't even show me all of it since it has a limit of 25000 characters. the fifth and sixth variables it didn't even find. I thought that maybe matlab doesn't work well with too long expressions and Mathematica/Maple can deal with them. at least I hoped.. Maybe there's still a chance with Mathematica.

Comment: Regardless of the algorithm (or system) employed, the problem is that the answer to a generic problem like this is doubly exponentially larger than the system being solved ($2^{2^n}$ where n is the number of parameters) so you'd need RAM the size of a hard drive to compute the answer.  And then what are you going to be able to with it?

Comment: Assuming I have the generic solution I can use it for my research (in computer vision) and assign values to the known parameters so I can get all the numeric solutions for the specific problem. eventually I need to find all the possible rotation matrices (if you read the original problem I'm trying to solve). but I can easily find the rotation matrix if I find the 6 variables in the question I posted here. I did not think I need huge memory just to find the general solution. You think anyone with strong computer can solve the problem just by running the matlab code I posted in the question?

Comment: I suspect that the answer could be terabytes in size. Even if it is "only" giga- or mega-bytes in size, it wouldn't be any more useful than a program that plugs in values into the generic problem and then calls a solver.  That said, if you can find someone with Maple 2017 on a machine with 64GB of RAM, it might be able to generate that answer.

Comment: I really don't understand. Why are these equations consuming so much memory? How can you evaluate how much memory they consume?

Comment: This system of equations is very generic, so its solutions are likely in the worst case scenario of being exponentially larger than the input.  There are 66 monomials in the input, so there could potentially be $2^{66}$ monomials in the output.  In many practical problems, a lot of these combine and cancel, but in this case, there are 24 parameters, so that doesn't happen.  $2^{66}$ monomials would take a million terabytes to store. (this is a bit hand-wavy - the complexity of solving polynomial systems in many variables is a very technical subject)

Answer (score 1):

Referring back to [the original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297050)
we are to solve the matrix equation
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\overline {{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 1}} } \;{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 1}}  = \overline {{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 2}} } \;{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 2}} 
} \tag{1.a}$$
where the overline denotes the transposed, and where
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 1}}  = {\bf P}_{\,{\bf 1}}  + {\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} \,{\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 1}} \quad {\bf T}_{\,{\bf 2}}  = {\bf P}_{\,{\bf 2}}  + {\bf V}_{\,{\bf 2}} \,{\bf \Lambda }_{\,\,{\bf 2}} 
} \tag{1.b}$$
with
$ {\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}}$ ,$ {\bf V}_{\,{\bf 2}}$ , $ {\bf P}_{\,{\bf 1}}$ ,$ {\bf P}_{\,{\bf 2}} $  given matrices
$ {\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 1}}$, ${\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 2}}$  diagonal matrices whose elements are the unknowns.

So the LHS of the equation can be written as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \overline {{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 1}} } \;{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 1}}  = \left( {\overline {{\bf P}_{\,{\bf 1}} }  + {\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 1}} \overline {{\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} } \,} \right)\left( {{\bf P}_{\,{\bf 1}}  + {\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} \,{\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 1}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\overline {{\bf P}_{\,{\bf 1}} } {\bf P}_{\,{\bf 1}}  + \overline {{\bf P}_{\,{\bf 1}} } {\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} \,{\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 1}}  + {\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 1}} \overline {{\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} } {\bf P}_{\,{\bf 1}}  + {\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 1}} \overline {{\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} } {\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} \,{\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 1}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \overline {\left( {{\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 1}}  + {\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} ^{ - 1} {\bf P}_{\,{\bf 1}} } \right)} \;\overline {{\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} } \,{\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} \;\left( {{\bf \Lambda }_{\,{\bf 1}}  + {\bf V}_{\,{\bf 1}} ^{ - 1} {\bf P}_{\,{\bf 1}} } \right) \cr} 
} \tag{2}$$
The matrix equation, being symmetric, translates into a system of $6$ quadratic equations into the $6$ unknowns,
$\lambda _{\,1,\,\,k}$,$\lambda _{\,2,\,\,k}$, with $k=1,2,3$.

Equating the diagonal elements, we get $3$ equations of the type
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
b_{\,1,\,\,k} \,\lambda _{\,1,\,\,k} ^{\,2}  + c_{\,1,\,\,k} \,\lambda _{\,1,\,\,k}  + d_{\,1,\,\,k}  = b_{\,2,\,\,k} \,\lambda _{\,2,\,\,k} ^{\,2}  + c_{\,2,\,\,k} \,\lambda _{\,2,\,\,k}  + d_{\,2,\,\,k} 
} \tag{3}$$
where
 - each (lateral) side is the length of one edge of the pyramid from the origin ($OT$ in the original post) and is therefore non-negative;
 - each side is therefore a vertical parabola, convex, standing totally above the $x$ axis;
 - the equality means that we are looking for a $y=s_k$ intersecting both parabolas;
 - because of the geometrical stem of the problem, we can limit and consider only positive values of the abscissas $\lambda$,
since we can in any case shift appropriately the points  $P$ and / or change the sign of the vectors $V$.

It remains however the possibility that a parabola might have the vertex at a positive abscissa, which is the case when
the normal from the origin to a line, intercepts it on the positive side of the (corresponding) $\lambda$.

By plotting the three couples of parabolas we get a picture of the situation, and can establish a minimum for each $s_k$.

We can now solve the three equations above to obtain $\lambda _{\,1,\,\,k} $ and $\lambda _{\,2,\,\,k} $ as functions of $s_k$.
Concerning the sign in front of the $\sqrt{\;}$, we can take only the plus  for the parabolas with the vertex in the negative abscissas.
For the others we shall appropriately consider also the minus.

Now we can feed the functions found for the $\lambda$s into the three remaining equations given by the off-diagonal elements 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left( {\overline {{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 1}} } \;{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 1}} } \right)_{\,1,\,2}  - \left( {\overline {{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 2}} } \;{\bf T}_{\,{\bf 2}} } \right)_{\,1,\,2}  = 0,\;\; \cdots 
} \tag{4}$$
to get $3$ equations in the following combination of the three unknowns $(s_{1} ,\, s_{2}),(s_{1} ,\, s_{3}),(s_{2} ,\, s_{3}) $, 
but they shall be replicated for the allowed  combinations of $\pm$ signs in the $\lambda$s expressions, as
commented above.

In the geometric perspective, we are at the point where, having fixed the pyramids edges to mutually have equal length $s_k$,
we are going to vary these so that the three dot products becomes equal.

Concerning the practical solution of  equations (4), their structure (see example below) does not allow to look for a straight method.

We can only think to a successive approximations method.

However we reached a stage that allows us to plot the three surfaces resulting from (4), and visually identify if and where could be 
a solution.
The picture below an example.  By successive "zooming" a solution has been 
found to exist in the range indicated.
But also, a second solution looks to be present around $s_{1}=2.03, \, s_{2}=2.75, \, s_{3}=5.8$, which complicates the picture.

[image: Rot_3Lines_2]

At present, I did not investigate further on these solutions, and did not go back to the
triangles they represent to check whether they can be rotated one onto the other.

Comment: Hi GCab, sorry for the huge delay. I will split my comment.
Actually the equations above can be solved in Maple but only with numerical coefficients. There's no analytical solution for these equations. It takes about 1-4 minutes to solve the equations and to find all the possible solutions of $t11, t12, t13, t21, t22, t23$. However, there's a nice trick that can be done (it's too long to show here) in order to reduce the above equations from 6 polynomial equations of 2nd degree to 3 polynomial equations of 4th degree.

Comment: The 3 equations are also not solvable analytically, but Maple can solve the numeric equations with just a few seconds (about 10-20 seconds). It really worked and I got all the desired rotation matrices. Just to let you know, not all the solutions in the equations are indeed the relevat points for finding the rotation only. You can find also redundant solutions that solve the equations but can not be done with rotation only (I think that they are mirror transformation and they can be done with rotation+translation).

Comment: But it's still good since you can easily check which solutions are redundant using Kabsch algorithm (with Kabsch you find the rotation matrix and translation vector of two sets of points that you found after solving the equations. if the norm of the translation vector is bigger than zero then this is a redundant solution and you can throw it away). The important thing is that you don't miss correct solutions that way and you really find all the possible rotation matrices (and sometimes 0 solutions since there's not always a solution to the problem).
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That you can solve it only numerically is almost certain. That there might be cases with no solution is also certain, just considering the case in which one of the sets is nearly co-planar.  Translations are not included in the scheme, but you may end to find rotations+reflection (negative det) if you not pay attention. But in conclusion,  I think that it **might** be possible to construct an algorithm, that performs all the necessary checks (and for that I would use the geometric scheme of the parabolas at the beginning of my answer).

Comment: I can assure you that you can get translation+rotation when solving the equations. I didn't fully check it but I suppose that any reflection can be done with rotation+translation. Otherwise, I don't know why I got rotation+translation in some of the solutions. But in any case, no matter whether I got only rotation or rotation+translation, the points always moved exactly to their corresponding points in the second set (exact transformation with no error). For me it wasn't obvious that the equations can be solved numerically (in Matlab it didn't work and I didn't know Maple until recently).

Comment: Referring always to your *original problem*, when you say "translation", do you refer to the triangle moving along its three lines (which occurs for sure), or to the translation of the lines (of their common point: which shall not occur in the adopted geometric scheme) ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. What triangle? when I say translation I mean a movement of all the lines in the set (or points when working with Kabsch) by the same 3D translation vector (x,y,z).

Comment: @David  Ah .., seems that you are not correlating this problem to the [original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297050) any more !? I have based this answer as a continuation of the precedent, and the geometric interpretation is an **essential basis**.

Comment: of course I am. why would you think that? The problem is exactly the same. nothing changed. since I want only rotations with no translations at all, I removed all the solutions of the original equations that refer to rotation+translation (which I think related to reflection). and I kept only the solutions related to rotations only (which is the original problem). I'm not sure we understand each other.